# How to move a subarray column to the first position of all subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
    [a] = 1,
    [b] = 'ABC',
    [c] = 'ABC',
[1] => Array (
    [a] = 2,
    [b] = 'DEF',
    [c] = 'DEF',
[2] => Array (
    [a] = 3,
    [b] = 'JKL',
    [c] = 'JKL',
```

How can I have my array become like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array (
    [b] = 'ABC',
    [a] = 1,
    [c] = 'ABC',
[1] => Array (
    [b] = 'DEF',
    [a] = 2,
    [c] = 'DEF',
[2] => Array (
    [b] = 'JKL',
    [a] = 3,
    [c] = 'JKL',
```

Can I sort it by string value "b" then "a" then "c" ?

Comment: After re-reading your question, your requirements can be interpreted in different ways.  Your subarrays are already sorted ASC based on column `b`'s value, so it looks like this is not what you need.  From your desired output, it appears that you just want to move the `b` column to the first position.  If this is not what you want, please edit/clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you just need to write your own compare function for it, and combine it with [uksort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uksort.php). In your case, you could use a function like this (`$input`is your input array, `$output` the result ldo):

```
$output = array_map(uksort($input, function ($a, $b) {
  if ($a === 'b') return -1;
  if ($a === 'c') return 1;
  if ($b === 'b') return 1;
  return -1;
}
```

You might want to rewrite the function, but the combination of `array_map` and `uksort` should get you started. Or don't;) since keys are unique, the four if s actually do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your task could be rephrased as "How to move an element to the first position of a subarray?"

This can be achieved without making any iterated function calls or comparisons.

Simply iterate each subarray, generate a single-element array that contains the column to be moved to the front, then use the union operator (`+`) to add the full subarray to it.  This will quietly overwrite `b` with its original value, but position it before all other elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/akn8U))

```
$array = [
    ['a' => 1, 'b' => 'ABC', 'c' => 'ABC'],
    ['a' => 2, 'b' => 'DEF', 'c' => 'DEF'],
    ['a' => 3, 'b' => 'JKL', 'c' => 'JKL']
];

var_export(
    array_map(function($subarray) {
        return ['b' => $subarray['b']] + $subarray;
    }, $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'b' => 'ABC',
    'a' => 1,
    'c' => 'ABC',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'b' => 'DEF',
    'a' => 2,
    'c' => 'DEF',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'b' => 'JKL',
    'a' => 3,
    'c' => 'JKL',
  ),
)
```

This outcome can be produced a multitude of ways -- this is just one.

Often this technique is not necessary when displaying associative data, but we cannot see how the data is used onward.

If this data is coming from a database, the most reasonable technique would be to use SQL sorting.

The same technique in my snippet can be used to bring multiple columns to the front of the subarrays; just nominate the order in the genetated subarray before the union operator.

If you wish to move all columns to a different position or if you have numeric keys in your subarrays, don't use the union operator; return the full subarray in the desired order (in other words, completely rewrite the subarray using variables as I have done with `'key' => $variable['key']`.